# Programmatically hide filter per category

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-community

I have custom field (custom attribute) on category edit page. It holds the list of attribute that need be removed when users view that particular category page.

How can I programmatically disable specific filters based on that list?

Answer (score 1):

Filters comes from `catalog/layer/view.phtml`
There you may add conditions something like

```
       <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
       <?php $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
          $Category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
          $currentCatId= $Category ->getId(); ?>
        <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>

                   <?php if($_filter->getName() == 'Price' && $currentCatId= 'YOUR_CATEGORY_ID'): ?>   
                          <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                               <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                               <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                           <?php endif; ?>
                   <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
```